# Canasta and the rules on invalid melding

Tags: canasta

Would like to know what happens when you come down with an invalid meld You have now exposed all your cards on the table. I was told you have to leave them down on the table and use them as discards. Until they are all gone. My question is is if you come down with a valid meld can your partner open and put her meld down? Or do you have to wait till all the cards that were exposed are discarded?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different rules that pertain to this and it will differ based on the exact rules being played at the time. Some rules list for the first meld you would take it back but have a penalty for next attempt. Others say you would take back the invalid meld and pay a point penalty.

The main point of having to leave the cards face up on the table if you expose them is to prevent partners from sharing information for their benefit.

[Rules](http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/canasta.html)

> If a player exposes any cards from his hand, but does not meld them, he must leave them face-up on the table, and discard them one at a time in subsequent turns. However, if these cards can be validly melded before they are discarded, he may do so, rather than discard them.
>
> If a player makes an invalid meld by adding more than three wild cards to a meld, he may either transfer the extra wild card(s) to another valid meld, discard them, or return them to his hand and take a 100-point penalty. (This penalty also applies to the initial meld.)

[More Rules](http://www.dummies.com/games/card-games/canasta/playing-canasta-making-the-first-meld-for-your-partnership/)

> If you put down an initial meld that doesn’t meet the minimum point requirement, you can put down additional melds on that same turn to make up the required total without penalty. You can also take back your attempt, but the minimum total you have to meet the next time you try goes up by 10 points — quite a severe penalty.

Comment: My question is is that if someone puts down an invalid meld and leave that meld down because those cards are exposed and uses them as discards can his partner now meld or does that person who melded  have to complete his meld to Officially come down

Comment: Why would the partner not be able to meld? And why would they have to complete the meld they tried when they are discarding the cards? That would just mean they might as well give up the game and start again as they won't ever be able to get a meld in once they mess up.