# Can cards from an invalid meld be used in a subsequent valid meld?

Tags: canasta

This is a follow-up to my previous question here: [Canasta and the rules on invalid melding](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38801/canasta-and-the-rules-on-invalid-melding/38802)

In Canasta, if the “partner” of the person who laid down an invalid meld after exposing her cards, now comes down with a valid meld, can she now use any of the cards in the “invalid” meld that are lying exposed?  Or are they only used for discards still?

Comment: Folks, it's all well and good to ask the OP questions and let them know how to use the site, but if you know what needs to be done, please just edit (or suggest an edit). It takes less time to retag a question than to ask the OP to.

Comment: After editing to include the game being asked about, this is certainly not unclear in the way folks previously noted. I'm not sure if it may need a little improvement still (I don't know canasta so I can't evaluate super well) or if it may be a duplicate, but I've reopened because the original close reason doesn't apply.

Comment: @Jefromi I still have a feeling that this was already answered on that other question, see my answer.

Comment: As was pointed out in Andrew Savinykh answer to this question the information is already in the question that is linked.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer to your previous question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/38802/2737) yes, you can use these in a valid meld. Here is the relevant quote:

> If a player exposes any cards from his hand, but does not meld them, he must leave them face-up on the table, and discard them one at a time in subsequent turns. **However, if these cards can be validly melded before they are discarded, he may do so**, rather than discard them.

As a side-note there are different rules and different variants of Canasta, and I do not believe there is one true way. That what makes difficult answering your question unambiguously.

For my Canasta games, I've written down my own version of Canasta rules, that I compiled from different sources on the web and got everyone at the table to agree to them. Since we are running a friendly non-commercial games, we simply re-deal the round if someone makes this mistake, because we trust that no one of us will do this intentionally. Anyway it happened only once or twice, so it has never been a problem for us.