# Canasta- Partner melds Wild cards 160 pts but we need 180. Penalty to 190. I meld w 3 wild cards but told I can't

Tags: canasta

Partner and I needed 180 pts to meld.  She melds 5 wild cards that only total 160 so penalty is now 190. After a few turns I now have 3 wild cards which I meld with other naturals for a total of 195.  I was told it's not legal since I saw my partner had 5 wild cards.  Is it legal?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but helpful: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43067/canasta-melding-with-insufficent-points?rq=1